# Access different levels of nested lists in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Suppose I have a list with the following format:

```
dataset = [["10", "asdf"], ["20", "jkl"], ["30", "bla"]]
```

I want to append text for each individual character in the second element of each nested list. I also want the x position of each letter to be determined by the first element of the list. So, for example, the x position of `a` should be `10`, for `s` - `11`, `d` - `12`... for `j`- `20`, for `k`- `21`, and so forth.

In the code I have so far, I only show the first letter, because I'm not iterating through the correct portion of the list:

```
chartBody.selectAll("exampletext")
                       .data(dataset)
                       .enter()
                       .append("text")
                       .attr("class", "exampletext")
                       .text(function(d) {
                            for (var i=0; i <= d[1].length; i++)
                                {
                                    return d[1][i];
                                }
                       })
                       .attr("x", function(d) {
                            for (var i=0; i <= d[1].length; i++)
                                {
                                    return xScale(+d[0]) + i; 
                                }
                       })
                       .attr("y", h/2);
```

Comment: d[2] is the third element in your "x" attribute function did you mean ```for (var i=0; i <= d[1].length; i++)```?

Comment: Yea, just fixed it, code still works the same

Comment: your text function and x attribute functions will run once per list item ["10", "asdf"]. It'll have one text attribute and one x attribute . Are you wanting to see a text of "a-10 s-11 d-12 f-13" for the text? What is the desired value for x? OR are you looking for 10 text/x attributes given these three nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you need this (it's really hard to read that output) but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/uNQA9/.

The important change was to build the list of letters and positions prior to feeding to d3:

```
var dataset, h, i, letter, pair, r, viewport, xScale, _i, _j, _len, _len1, _ref;

dataset = [["10", "asdf"], ["20", "jkl"], ["30", "bla"]];

r = [];    
i = 0;

/*loop each pair, push into a new array */


for (_i = 0, _len = dataset.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  pair = dataset[_i];
  i = 0;
  _ref = pair[1];
  for (_j = 0, _len1 = _ref.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
    letter = _ref[_j];
    r.push([+pair[0] + i, letter]);
    i++;
  }
}
```

That JS is ugly (but uber compliant) because I got it from this bit of (nicely readable) coffeescript:

```
dataset = [["10", "asdf"], ["20", "jkl"], ["30", "bla"]]
r = []
i = 0 
#loop each pair, push into a new array
for pair in dataset
  i = 0
  for letter in pair[1]
    r.push([+(pair[0]) + i, letter]) 
    i++
```

I made a slightly more readable version here: http://jsfiddle.net/UtUeP/. If you want to pump up the difference between the letters, check out the d3 colors functions like: `d3.scale.category10()`: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales

Comment: This answer works well when the arrays are not large, as in your perfect examples... but making extra arrays appears to be too computationally heavy when the strings in particular can be large, meaning 100s-1000s of characters. When implementing this code to mine, the letters just don't show up, even though r shows up on the console (1289 characters = 1289 arrays!) But I didn't know of coffeescript before this :/ thanks!

Comment: sure, but think about how small those things are in memory, 1200 characters in 1200 array locations isn't that big of a deal memory-wise; plus, if you need 1200 characters on screen, well, why would you need that many? If you're rendering a page of text with d3 it's a bad idea

Comment: I'm trying to build a mini genome browser, to visualize DNA sequences. It's not a legit browser where you can view the entire genome or even chromosome, it's designed to look one gene at a time. A gene can be 1000s to even 10000s of base pairs (characters) long. I want the user to be able to zoom in, and see the position of each base pair. So the truth is, my arrays look like this: `[["50376619", "AAAACAACGGAAGGAAAC..."], ["50384973", "AGATAAGAAGATAGTTAA..."], ...]` I guess I was trying to simplify the question a bit

Comment: I'm sorry, it worked! I forgot to put the xScale on my x attribute. Nice work, thanks a lot!

Comment: That's an interesting application of D3, you should post it on github when it's done.